# How do I migrate data from some On-Premise SQL Database to Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, data-migration

I have an existing database with several tables in on-premise SQL Database.  In AZURE SQL Database, I have created 2 databases i.e. ***DatabaseA*** and ***DatabaseB***.  What I want to do is just load data from 1 table in on-prem SQL Database, do some staging and then load some fields into ***DatabaseA*** and some to ***DatabaseB***.

What is the best way to achieve this **DATA** migration? (just to be clear, I don't want to migrate the whole database)

In a nutshell, I want to insert data into Azure SQL Databases (***DatabaseA*** and ***DatabaseB***) from my ON-PREM SQL Database....

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS) to create a project that will load that from the SQL Server instance into both databases. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-sql-database-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15) you will find an example, you just need to add any transformation of data you need.